# How to make results of a join statement a new table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have the following mysql query. How can i make the result of the query be a new table;

```
SELECT t1.referree AS LEVEL1, t2.referree AS LEVEL2, t3.referree AS LEVEL3, t4.referree AS LEVEL4, t5.referree AS LEVEL5, t6.referree AS LEVEL6, t7.referree AS LEVEL7, t8.referree AS LEVEL8, t9.referree AS LEVEL9, t10.referree LEVEL10, t11.referree AS LEVEL11
                                        FROM referrals AS t1
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t2 ON t2.referrer = t1.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t3 ON t3.referrer = t2.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t4 ON t4.referrer = t3.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t5 ON t5.referrer = t4.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t6 ON t6.referrer = t5.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t7 ON t7.referrer = t6.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t8 ON t8.referrer = t7.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t9 ON t9.referrer = t8.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t10 ON t10.referrer = t9.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t11 ON t11.referrer = t10.referree
                                        WHERE t1.referrer ='2'));
```

Comment: i think you need to create View . just create the view instead of table

Comment: Thanks @JYoThI , help me achieve it please

Comment: take  a look on my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple create the `view` instead of `table`

view is nothing but , a view is a `virtual table` based on the `result-set` of an `SQL statement`.

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT t1.referree .....
```

[Take look on documentation for more info about view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @JYoThl

Answer (score 0):

You can create one table from another by adding a SELECT statement at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl [AS] SELECT select_statement;
```

Replace the select statement with the select statement that you have above.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html

Edit: As jyothi suggested in a comment, you might wanna use a View instead of a new table in this case. If that's the case, you could use something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT select_statement;
```

Ref: http://www.guru99.com/views.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arvind

Answer (score 0):

assuming all the columns are varchar(10) datatype, try this syntax :

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (Level1 varchar(10),Level2 varchar(10),Level3 varchar(10),Level4 varchar(10),Level5 varchar(10),Level6 varchar(10),Level7 varchar(10),Level8 varchar(10),Level9 varchar(10),Level10 varchar(10),Level11 varchar(10))
SELECT 
t1.referree AS LEVEL1, 
t2.referree AS LEVEL2,
 t3.referree AS LEVEL3, 
t4.referree AS LEVEL4, 
t5.referree AS LEVEL5, 
t6.referree AS LEVEL6, 
t7.referree AS LEVEL7, 
t8.referree AS LEVEL8, 
t9.referree AS LEVEL9, 
t10.referree LEVEL10, 
t11.referree AS LEVEL11 
FROM 
referrals AS t1 LEFT JOIN referrals AS t2 
ON t2.referrer = t1.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t3 
ON t3.referrer = t2.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t4 
ON t4.referrer = t3.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t5 
ON t5.referrer = t4.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t6 
ON t6.referrer = t5.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t7 
ON t7.referrer = t6.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t8 
ON t8.referrer = t7.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t9 
ON t9.referrer = t8.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t10 
ON t10.referrer = t9.referree 
LEFT JOIN referrals AS t11 
ON t11.referrer = t10.referree 
WHERE 
t1.referrer ='2'));
```

Comment: @PeterMutai : glad to help. So did you create view or new table ?